# Array element as Json field

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

Basically I have a json say..
`collectionData = {'customerName':'Ashish','phone':'1234567'}`
Now I have an array containing json fieldnames like..

```
array = ['customerName','phone'];
```

Now I want to perform this operation :

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(collectionData.array[i]);
}
```

Why this code is giving me error? Thanks is advance

Comment: Use bracket notation instead (`console.log(collectionData[array[i]]);`)

Comment: Hey thanks, for quick response.. it worked!!!

Comment: @raina77ow. OP was asking _Why this code is giving me error?_ shouldn't we consider answering to that part too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to access them using bracket notation. Coz when you do that using `.` dot notation what happens is

```
console.log(collectionData.array[0])  // undefined - 
//it looks for .array[0] property which gives you undefined
```

That's why it is advised to use bracket notation in such cases

Now consider the following

```
  console.log(collectionData[array[0]])
```

This will first resolve `array[0]` to `customerName` and will give you value if exists.

If you still want to access using dot notation there is still a way to do that. Something like

```js
var collectionData = {'customerName':'Ashish','phone':'1234567'}
var array = ['customerName','phone'];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
console.log(eval('collectionData.'+array[i]))
```